# Connect Azure VMs using Vnet peering

Tags: azure

I have more than one subscription to Windows Azure and would like to have machines talking to each other using VNET Peering

For example

An SQL Server in one subscription and an application server in another, I want the application to use sql server, where the sql server will not have public IP.

Answer (score 0):

To create the vnet peering from different subscriptions, you can use the Azure CLI or Azure PowerShell command or Azure portal to achieve it. But you need to make sure if the subscriptions belong to different tenants. If they belong to different tenants, you just can use Azure CLI and Azure PowerShell.

> Portal does not have support to peer virtual networks belonging to
>   subscriptions from different Active Directory Tenants.
>
> Note that Cloud Shell has limitations in switching subscriptions and
>   tenants due to which VNet Peering or Global VNet Peering between VNets
>   belonging to subscriptions in different Azure Active Directory Tenants
>   will not work. Please use PowerShell or CLI.

You can follow the steps in [Create Vnet Peering through the Azure Portal, Azure PowerShell, and Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/create-peering-different-subscriptions).